# Use find to identify directories with more than X Megabytes

Tags: bash, shell

So I've been trying to solve a university exercise that asks to create a script that identifies directories whose size is greater than a given dimension.

I was thinking about using find to do this, using the following command:

```
find -type d -size +100M
```

This doesn't seem to work though. If I try to use it with `type f` it identifies the files that meets the criteria, but it doesn't seem to work for directories.

Is there a way to use find to do this? If not, what is the most simple way of identifying those directories?

Comment: Directory sizes are measured by block size, which is typically 4096 bytes but dependent on filesystem. Look at `du -sh`.

Comment: From the perspective of the operating system and `find` the "size" of a directory is only the size of a text file containing all *names* of the *direct* children of that directory. To compute the size it takes to store all those children, their children, and so on, the operating system has to recursively iterate  all children and sum up their sizes. This is what `du -s` does.

Comment: @erip, true, but that's the size of the directory itself, not the files within it, so it's not what the OP means to measure.

Comment: Short form: `find` isn't the appropriate tool for this job, unless you want to do the work of writing code that adds up the size of contents therein after listing files' names and sizes individually. Postprocessing `du` output is a better approach.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy understood. I'm explaining why `find` isn't going to do the job (easily).

Answer (score 2):

Using [`du`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/du-invocation.html#du-invocation) command as part of GNU *coreutils* to summarize device usage (space) for directories (on the current level) with a threshold param `-t` to exclude entries smaller than `100M`:

```
du -sh -t 100M ./*
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't knew about this option. Can you give a list of wide-spread implementations that support it? [`-t` is not specified by posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/du.html).

Comment: @Socowi, it should work on all "open" POSIX systems which additionally supplied with GNU tools/coreutils

Comment: In other words: you are using GNU coreutils and did not look up any other implementations. The `du` from *Open*BSD doesn't seem to support this ([man](https://man.openbsd.org/du.1)), neither does the `du` from mac os ([man](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/du/)), nor `busybox` ([--help](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#du)). But freeBSD supports it too.

Comment: @Socowi : i dunno how outdated ur `mac` `man` page link is, but my `macOS 13.2` built-in `du` supports `-t` flag. ps : your link for `mac` one has "June 2, 2004" at bottom of it - rather outdated I'd say.

Comment: ps : tracing through `FreeBSD` man pages hosted at `freebsd.org` of all releases seem to point to `-t` flag being added as of  `FreeBSD 8.2`, with a timestamp of `2008-11-06`, so one can probably assume any major `BSD`-based systems from last 12 years would have the `-t` flag.

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Thank you for the correction regarding macs. I don't have access to a mac, so I can only check pages like the one linked above. unix.com has two sets of manpages for macs [OS X 10.6.2](https://www.unix.com/man-page-osx-repository.php) and [macOS 10.14 Mojave](https://www.unix.com/man-page-mojave-repository.php). The date on a specific manpage only shows when the program was last updated. Mac os ships with a lot of outdated utils. Above, I accidentally chose mac 10.6.2 (the older OS) whose [`man du` is from 2006](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/du/) (not 2004!).

Comment: Also, only because FreeBSD has `-t` since a while (as I already said) that doesn't mean other BSDs have it too. OpenBSD still doesn't have it (again; as I already said).

Comment: @Socowi : you misread the 2014 page. That page has 2 `man` pages  : `du` on top and `df` right beneath it, and you've accidentally quoted from the `df` one instead. As for `OpenBSD`, their `du` page specifically mentioned it's being branched off from the `FreeBSD` one, so not having `-t` is an odd but reasonable omission

Comment: @RAREKpopManifesto Thank you for the correction again. It is much appreciated! The quote from the `-t` option was indeed from `df`. Hence I deleted that comment.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of the operating system and `find` the "size" of a directory is only the size of a text file containing all *names* of the *direct* children of that dir. To compute the size it takes to store all those children, their children, and so on, the operating system has to recursively iterate  all children and sum up their sizes. This is what `du -s` does for a single dir.

You could use `find` or some other program to execute `du` for each dir in your tree (e.g. [as done by Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75566724/6770384)) but that is slow and computes the same sizes of subsubdirs over and over again.
If you need the list **only for humans** to look at, there might be an easier, faster, and even prettier solution:

`tree`* prints a file tree as such and can annotate each entry with its disk size. Example:

```
├── [ 26K]  thisIsADirectory
│   ├── [  28]  someFile
│   ├── [1.0K]  thisIsAnotherDir
│   │   └── [ 512]  anotherFile
│   ├── [1.3K]  file1
│   ├── [1.0K]  file2
└── [ 514]  thisIsAlsoADir
    └── [   2]  someFile
```

`tree`'s `-d` option only lists directories, and with `grep` you can easily filter out those dirs that are 100MB or bigger:

```
tree --du -h -d | grep -E ' \[ *[0-9]{3,}([.0-9]*)?M\] '
```

* <sup>There might be different implementations of `tree` that may or may not support features used here. I know only one implementation, the one by Steve Baker et al. Therefore I think this should be fairly portable.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- 'size of a directory' encompasses all subdirectories (ie, you're not limited to counting *just* files in the directory) so ...
- if a 'child' directory meets the threshold then so will the 'parent' directory

One `du/awk` idea for locating directories that are 100M+ in size:

```
du -m . | awk '$1>=100'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?!

```
shopt -s globstar # enable recursion
du -s /var/**/*/ | awk '($1 > (1024*10O))'
```